# C# filter String with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm not familiar with the regex, However I think that REGEX could help me a lot to resolve my problem.

I have 2 kind of string in a big `List<string> str` (with or without description) :

```
str[0] = "[toto]";
str[1] = "[toto] descriptionToto";
str[2] = "[titi]";
str[3] = "[titi] descriptionTiti";
str[4] = "[tata]";
str[5] = "[tata] descriptionTata";
```

The list isn't really ordered.
I would parse all my list then format datas depending on what I will find inside.

If I find: `"[toto]"` I would like to get to set `str[0]="toto"`

and If I find `"[toto] descriptionToto"` I would like to get to set `str[1]="descriptionToto"`

Do you have any ideas of the better way to get this result please ?

Comment: In the first case I just would like to rid the "[" "]" and on the other one I would like to delete this part "[contains] ". I could cut the string if I find space and just use a Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "") If I don't find any space, but is it better/faster to use the Replace than to use the REGEX ?

Comment: Usually regex isn't faster, but does require less lines of code and could produce more readable code.

Comment: You could use the [String.Trim Method (Char())](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx). Is there a requirement that there be a `[toto]` to match with a `[toto] descriptionToto`?

Comment: can't you order the data, like str.OrderBy(x => x);

Comment: No, It's just a transformation, there is no link between all entries. the result just must be like that : `[toto]` => `toto` and `[toto] description` => `description`

Answer (score 1):

There are two regex options if you ask me:

1. Make a regex pattern with two capturing groups, then use group 1 or group 2 depending on whether group 1 is empty. In this case you'd use named capturing groups to get a clear relationship between the pattern and the code
2. Make a regex that matches *string type 1* **or** *string type 2*, in which case you would get your end result directly from regex

If you're going for speed, using `str[0].IndexOf(']')` would get most of the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than regex, I'd be inclined to just use string.split, something along the lines of:

```
string[] tokens = str[0].Split(new Char [] {'[', ']'});
if (tokens[2] == "") {
    str = tokens[1];
} else {
    str = tokens[2];
}
```

Comment: It works thanks. The "[" "]" are the only chars in each string instead of the space or all others.

Answer (score 1):

You can use single regex:

```
string s = Regex.Match(str[0], @"(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=]$)|(?<=] ).*").Value;
```

Idea is simple: if the text is ended with `]` and there is no other `]`, then take everything between `[ ]`, otherwise take everything after first `]`.

Sample code:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string> {
    "[toto]",
    "[toto] descriptionToto",
    "[titi]",
    "[titi] descriptionTiti",
    "[tata]",
    "[tata] descriptionTata" };
foreach(string str in strList)
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=]$)|(?<=] ).*").Value);
```

Sample output:

```
toto
descriptionToto
titi
descriptionTiti
tata
descriptionTata
```

Comment: This would handle see ref [5] in the description?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match("[toto] see ref [5]", @"(?<=\[).*(?=]$)|(?<=] ).*").Value);`

Comment: @sln Sorry, didn't understand your comment right. Thanks for the notice. That case also can be resolved by replacing first `.*` with `[^\]]*`.

Comment: `[toto see ref [5]` malformed?

Comment: @sln There is no such requirement in topic starter question. Though it still matches `toto see ref [5`, which I presume is correct.

Comment: This one is not malformed but has a hold on it. `(temporary)[toto] toto description` Most questions don't state the obvious but they usually put it in positional context.

Comment: @sln So what do you expect to extract from this text? I think we shouldn't think for questioner and solve the given problem, not theoretical one.

Comment: He is looking for a replacement, not an extraction. I would say to not replace anything if its not in the valid form laid out.

Answer (score 0):

if you are planning to get just the description for those that contain description:

you can do a split at a space char - " " and store the second element of the array in str[1] which would be the description.
If there's no description, a space would not exist.
So do a loop and then in an array store : list.Split(' '). This will split the str with description into two elements. 
so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
           string words[] = str[i].Split(' ')
           if words.length > 1 
           {str[i] = word[1];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are code strings and not literal variable notation this should work.
The replacement just catenates capture group 1 and 2.

Find:  `^\s*(?:\[([^\[\]]*)\]\s*|\[[^\[\]]*\]\s*((?:\s*\S)+\s*))$`
Replace:  `"$1$2"`

```
 ^ 
 \s* 
 (?:
      \[  
      ( [^\[\]]* )                # (1)
      \]   \s* 
   |  
      \[  [^\[\]]* \]
      \s*  
      (                           # (2 start)
           (?: \s* \S )+
           \s* 
      )                           # (2 end)
 )
 $
```

Dot-Net test case

```
 string str1 = "[titi]";
 Console.WriteLine( Regex.Replace(str1, @"^\s*(?:\[([^\[\]]*)\]\s*|\[[^\[\]]*\]\s*((?:\s*\S)+\s*))$", @"$1$2"));
 string str2 = "[titi] descriptionTiti";
 Console.WriteLine( Regex.Replace(str2, @"^\s*(?:\[([^\[\]]*)\]\s*|\[[^\[\]]*\]\s*((?:\s*\S)+\s*))$", @"$1$2"));
```

Output >>

```
 titi
 descriptionTiti
```